# Enter no TextBox chamando evento de botão

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quando eu aperto enter em um textbox, ele esta chamando o "FiltroGridView" e depois ele chama o evento do botão.

```
<div class="TextRight">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBuscaNome" runat="server" CssClass="text_field upper-case" OnTextChanged="FiltroGridView" />
</div>
```

Não sei se formulei bem a pergunta, pois estou fazendo dessa forma mas não sei se e a mais correta.

Criei um hidden

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfGrid" runat="server" />
```

E no final do "FiltroGridView" coloco o value =1

```
hfData.Value = "1";
```

E vejo se ele e 1 no evento do botão.(Pois ele sempre entra aqui no submit)

```
if (hfData.Value == "1")
return
```

Comment: Qual é o erro? OnTextChanged="FiltroGridView"

Comment: Qual o o objetivo? Não entrar no evento?